# Is there a name for the PRG pattern that doesn't redirect on failed validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post-redirect-get

My website follows the Post-Redirect-Get pattern.
There seems to be 2 ways to deal with failed validation.  Either:

- Render the page with validation messages
- Temporarily store the validation messages, and redirect to a GET that shows the messages

Do both of these implementations follow the PRG pattern?
Is there a more specific way to describe either of these patterns?

I am asking primarily for educational sake.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599086/how-are-server-side-errors-handled-in-post-redirect-get-pattern

Comment: I was also looking for some benefits & drawbacks of each approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is another one about displaying messages after the redirect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058497/how-to-display-messages-to-the-user-after-a-post-http-redirect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no one has answered, I'm going to suggest my own answer.

**PRG Strict** means that the POST redirects *even if* there is a validation error. It temporarily stores the validation messages, redirects to the same URL, and displays the validation messages.

**PRG Loose** means that the POST does not redirect when there are validation errors.  The form will be redisplayed, along with the error messages.

How does this sound?