# Express.js form handling and error checking – the right way

Tags: forms, node.js, express

I have a form in a template, which I render upon `GET` requests:

```
app.get('/register', function (req, res) {
  res.render('register', {
      title: 'Register'
    , twitterDetails: req.session.twitterDetails
    }
  );
});
```

I then process the form in a `POST` request:

```
app.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
  // Generic validation
  req.assert('name', 'Name is empty').notEmpty();
  req.assert('username', 'Username is empty').notEmpty();
  // Email validation
  req.assert('email', 'Email is invalid.').isEmail();
  req.assert('email', 'Email field is empty').notEmpty();
  // Password validation
  req.assert('password', 'Password too short. Must be 6 characters or more.').len(6);
  req.assert('password', 'Passwords do not match.').is(req.body.confirmPassword);
  req.assert('password', 'Password field is empty').notEmpty();
  req.assert('confirmPassword', 'Confirm password field is empty').notEmpty();
  var errors = req.validationErrors(true);
  if (errors) {
    console.log(errors);
    // What do to if there are errors?
  }
  // If there are no errors, continue handling the form…
});
```

In this form handler, I am checking for errors with the `express-validator` module. This is fine, but my question is what to do if there are errors. AFAIK, there are two options:

1. Redirect the user to `/register`, using `req.flash` to pass errors to the next request
2. Re-render the template and pass errors directly to the template

With the first option, I risk losing form data by taking the user away from the `POST`. I can preempt the form with the data they filled in using `req.flash` as well, but this will disappear when the page is refreshed.

With the second option, I am repeating myself – especially if I am sending lots of variables to the template, which will all have to be repeated. I will also need to pass through the template all of the form data and fill in the form with those values.

What is the correct procedure for handling a form like this?

Comment: i load the entered form data into js on the client side, and re-populate the form w/ errors highlighted w/o ever touching my view.

Comment: Interesting. So you AJAX the form data to the `POST` request, and populate errors on the client-side with JavaScript?

Comment: exactly. keeps the view much cleaner not having <%= req.errors.fname ? req.errors.fname.value : '' %> all over the place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use option 1. This is called the [POST/Redirect/GET pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) and is used everywhere.

If you're afraid of losing your data, then use sessions. That's what they're for. Keeping state during a session.

Don't forget that HTTP is stateless.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for – an established principle. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should rather use option 2 in my opinion.

The POST/Redirect/GET pattern mostly applies to successful submissions by the user and helps to avoid duplicated posts. That does not mean you should use it for **failed submissions** as well.

For failed submissions it is common practice to not redirect to another page but simply re-render the form with error messages.

Option 1 does improve usability slightly in that users will not resubmit when refreshing the page after a failed submission attempt. On the other hand, it is much more complex to handle as it requires to store the form data in the session or the GET parameters.

So overall: while Option 1 is probably the best in terms of usability, option 2 is still common practice and way more practical.

See also: [How are server side errors handled in Post/Redirect/Get pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599086/how-are-server-side-errors-handled-in-post-redirect-get-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Heres an example:

I add this to the  tag at the bottom of the page inside my ./views/layout.ejs:

```
<script>
var app = window.app || {};
app.req = app.req || {};
app.req.err = <%- JSON.stringify(err) %>;
app.req.q = <%- JSON.stringify(q) %>;
</script>
```

Example real data from a POST error:

```
app.req.err = {"email":{"param":"email","msg":"Enter email","value":""}};
app.req.q = {"username":"chovy","email":"","password":"somepassword"};
```

I have middleware on each POST that does this:

```
  res.locals.q = req.body;
  res.locals.err = false;
```

If I encounter an error, then I populate it: ./routes/signup.js:

```
  req.assert('email', 'Enter email').notEmpty().isEmail();
  req.assert('username', 'Enter username').notEmpty().isAlphanumeric().len(3,20);
  req.assert('password', 'Enter password').notEmpty().notContains(' ').len(5,20);

  res.locals.err = req.validationErrors(true);
```

Then my global client side js runs this routine on every page load, which basically checks for app.req.err and handles form errors:

```
app.utils.form.errors();
```

Here is the function:

```
app.utils.form.errors = function(err){
    err = err || app.req.err;
    app.utils.form.prefill();
    for ( var e in err ) {
        var $field = $('[name='+e+']'),
        $el = $field.parents('p');

        $el.addClass('err');
        $el.append('<span class="msg">'+err[e].msg+'</span>');
    }
};
```

Prefill the form from app.req.q:

```
app.utils.form.prefill = function(){
    for ( var param in app.req.q ) {
        var $field = $('[name='+param+']');
        $field.val(app.req.q[param]);
    }
};
```

You can see it in action if you go to this signup form and just submit it blank, and then view source: http://wishd.me/signup  the javascript is in http://wishd.me/app.js

The trick is leaving enough room for inline error messages on your form fields because all errors will be handled the same regardless of which field it is on. Of course I do have a few exceptions with css that might re-position the inline error message, color the label red, etc.

http://wishd.me/style.css look for .err class

Comment: Thanks but I prefer to render everything view-wise on the server. No ajax for my needs.

Comment: this isn't ajax. but the benefit here is you don' thave conditional logic all over the  place in your views for supporting errors and pre-populating data. I found that very messy.

Comment: If you use mixins, your views won't get messy!

Comment: got an example of a mixin?

Answer (score 1):

I am working with expressjs4.0 to repopulate the forms fields after validation you do:

```
router.route('/posts/new')
 .get(function(req, res) {
 res.render('posts/new', new Post({}));
});
```

The second argument in res.render below will set some variables in the view.

```
res.render('posts/new', new Post({}));
```

In my view I then set my form fields as follows:

```
...
<input type="text" name="title" value="<%- post.title %>">
<textarea name="article"><%- post.article %></textarea>
...
```

When you submit this form, it should be caught by your router like so:

```
router.route('/posts')
  .post(function(req, res) {
    var post = new Post(req.body)
      post.save(function(err) {
       if (err) {
         res.locals.errors = err.errors;
         res.locals.post = post;
         return res.render('posts/new');
       }
      return res.redirect('/posts');
  });
  ...
})
```

This line of code, resets the form fields in your view

```
res.locals.post = post;
```

I hope someone finds this useful ;)